# Unit tests in Django for Content type model

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, tdd

I'm fairly new to Django and have worked through some Test Driven Development. I try to adhere to the principles of TDD, but there are some contexts where I don't know how to proceed (like the model below). I have a model that is very similar to what I show here. Essentially, the idea is to construct a book. Sometimes that book consists of chapters, other times the book has chapters and other books included. So, my question really about trying to test until I get to a model similar to the one below with the same functionality. I've tested this model in my python shell and it outputs how I expected it to, but I would like something more robust. 
I also want to be able to use this model in the core of my project and need to be able to test it as I continue to build on top. What would be some good example unit tests for testing a model like this? Or any advice on where to look for tests that work with ContentType and other abstract models? Thanks!

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.contenttypes import generic
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

class Element(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Chapter(Element):
    body = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.body

class Book(Element):
    description = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.description

class BookElement(models.Model):
    protocol_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    element_content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    element_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    element = generic.GenericForeignKey('element_content_type', 'element_id')
    # Sort order, heavy things sink.
    element_weight = models.PositiveIntegerField()

def __unicode__(self):
    return u'%s %s' % (self.protocol_id, self.element , self.element_weight)
```

**Update**
Here is a test I worked out for entering elements into the database and retrieving them. It works, but seems long tests more than one thing. If there is a better way, I am open to suggestions.

```
class BookAndChapterModelTest(TestCase):

    def test_saving_and_retrieving_book_elements(self):
        # input data objects and save
        book = Book()
        book.title = "First book"
        book.description = "Testing, round one"
        book.save()

        first_chapter = Chapter()
        first_chapter.title = 'step 1'
        first_chapter.body ='This is step 1'
        first_chapter.save()

        second_chapter = Chapter()
        second_chapter.title = 'step 2'
        second_chapter.body = 'This is step 2'
        second_chapter.save()

        # link content types to chapter or book model
        chapter_ct = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(first_chapter)
        book_ct = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(book)

        # Assemble BookElement order by weight of chapter or book
        BookElement.objects.create(
            book_id=book.pk,
            element_content_type=chapter_ct, 
            element_id=first_chapter.pk, 
            element_weight='1')
        BookElement.objects.create(
            book_id=book.pk, 
            element_content_type=chapter_ct, 
            element_id=second_chapter.pk, 
            element_weight='2')
        BookElement.objects.create(
            book_id=book.pk, 
            element_content_type=book_ct, 
            element_id=book.pk, 
            element_weight='3')

        # Test number of elements
        saved_book_element = BookElement.objects.all()
        self.assertEqual(saved_book_element.count(), 3)

        # Test elements are in the proper position based on weighting
        first_book_element = saved_book_element[0]
        self.assertEqual(str(first_book_element), 'This is step 1')
        third_book_element = saved_book_element[2]
        self.assertEqual(str(third_book_element), "Testing, round one")
```

Answer (score 0):

factory-boy to the rescue!  it makes testing fun fun

http://factoryboy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/examples.html

Comment: I have never used factory-boy. Could you elaborate a little more about how to incorporate it?